# Taskwarrior: how to change the format of "Age"

Tags: linux, taskwarrior

I would like the "Age" to be more precise, not just in hours, but also minutes.
How do I change this?
When I type 'task' I get:

```
ID Age  Description        Urg 
 1 1h   Conditional types.    0
```

How do I make it so that "Age" has more precision, such as:

```
ID Age      Description        Urg 
 1 1h 23m   Conditional types.    0
```

Comment: default reports use `entry.age` you can see possible formats with `task columns entry` but no option for a precision is available there.

Comment: So you are saying what I want to do cannot be done? sorry I didn't understand the wording, "you can see possible formats" "but no option is available". Thanks.

Comment: That's correct in code: https://github.com/GothenburgBitFactory/taskwarrior/blob/41608dc35fee0390d4679146034952fb12186053/src/columns/ColTypeDate.cpp#L132 all formats showing `Duration` are using `formatVague` implemented here https://github.com/GothenburgBitFactory/libshared/blob/47c3262fa97c4b69542040d39be6c516c38d0e57/src/Duration.cpp#L494